# What is the reason for reassigning the initialized pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently learning c posix sockets. In the provided example https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html the `struct ifaddrs *ifaddr` gets filled with all IP/interface/network info, using the 'getifaddrs(&ifaddr)' function. Then all info should be displayed by iterating through the ifaddr linked list.

In that context the `ifaddr` is assigned to a new `ifa struct ifaddrs = ifaddr` in the `for (struct ifaddrs *ifa = ifaddr; ....)` loop. What is the reason to make a new variable, instead of using the the already before initialized `ifaddr` to iterate through the list?

Answer (score 1):

The original pointer populated via `getifaddrs` must be passed to `freeifaddrs` when it is no longer in use.

By using a separate pointer variable in the `for` loop, we retain the original value of `ifaddr` so it can be passed to `freeifaddrs`.

Comment: Thanks - think I got it. So in other words, asure the original ```ifaddr``` does not get modified and the memory (allocated by ```getifaddr``` ) will be freed.